# To print a pattern in python using nested for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Ok I am a beginner in Python.

The pattern to be printed w/ nested loop:

```
1@
1#3#
1@3@5@
1#3#5#7#
```

(For loop preferred)

Thanks.

This is the code I tried:

```py
n = int(input("Enter no:"))
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, 2 * i):
        if j % 2 == 0:
            print("#", end="")
        else:
            print(str(j), end="@")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Enter no:7
1@
1@#3@
1@#3@#5@
1@#3@#5@#7@
1@#3@#5@#7@#9@
1@#3@#5@#7@#9@#11@
1@#3@#5@#7@#9@#11@#13@
```

"@" seems to come every line and "#" is not printed every 2nd line

Comment: Why `1@3@5` instead of `1@3@5@`?

Comment: Thank u...I edited it now

Comment: The only difference between even and odd rows is *what* character you print between numbers, so that decision should be based on `i`, not `j`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter) has pointed out in the comments, the difference between even and odd rows should be based on the value of `i` and not `j`.

Here is your code with aforementioned modification together with the updated printing:

```py
n = int(input("Enter no:"))
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, 2 * i, 2):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(f"{j}#", end="")
        else:
            print(f"{j}@",end="")
    print()
```

This is the output I got when I ran the code with the input value of `7`:

```
1@
1#3#
1@3@5@
1#3#5#7#
1@3@5@7@9@
1#3#5#7#9#11#
1@3@5@7@9@11@13@
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to keep an `if` condition inside the loop: you could simply use an indexed array of characters:

```
seps = '@#'
n = int(input("Enter no:"))
for i in range(n):            # loop on the lines
    sep = seps[i%2]
    for j in range(i+1):      # loop over odd numbers
        print(1+2*j, end=sep)
    print()                   # do not forget the end of line...
```

or even shorter:

```
seps = '@#'
n = int(input("Enter no:"))
for i in range(n):            # loop on the lines
    print(*(1+2*j for j in range(i+1)), '', sep=seps[i%2])
```